# With Bootrap how can use two different col-sm-* classes on two different Media Queries?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

In my application I have two different Small size Media Queries

`@media only screen and (min-width : 480px)` and `@media only screen and (min-width : 320px)`

But I want the 320px width to use the `col-xs-12` and size 480px with `col-sx-6` class?

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3" id="buttonCol">        
     <div class="frame"> 
         <div id="buttonWrapper1">
            <div id="overlay2">
                <img src="img/enter-01.png"  id="enterButton" >
            </div>
         </div>
     </div>   
</div>
```

Is this possible and if so how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the div twice as shown below with different id's and hide the one which you dont want to show in the media query using 
display:none;

```
   @media only screen and (min-width : 480px)
    #buttoncol320{
    display:none;
   }
     @media only screen and (min-width : 320px)
    #buttoncol480{
    display:none;
    }

    <div class="col-xs-12" id="buttonCol320">  
    </div>

      <div class="col-sx-6" id="buttonCol480">  
     </div>
```

Hope this gives want you want!

Comment: Interesting. It's seems hacky but could work. I'll give it a try

Comment: glad that helped you!

Answer (score 1):

That's possible but goes a bit outside of the purpose of using bootstrap grid layouts. You just need to overwrite the css rules. Copy the rules from the bootstrap stylesheet and paste them in your own stylesheet in the right media queries making the desired adjusments.

Note: If you're aiming at having different breakpoints in your media queries I would advise you not to use bootstrap's grid but to make your own. You can import just the necessary features of the framework that suit your needs.

Comment: Okay, so it sounds like I'll need to roll my own grid then.